# Entity Framework(Code First to an existing database) - overwrite a connection string in app.config at runtime

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

I need to connect my app(windows forms) to a SQL Server Database dynamically and i have in my app.config, 3 connection strings(where 1 of them i want to change dynamically).

Bellow is the app.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NfceConnPortalInterno"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
         connectionString="Data Source=lab;Initial Catalog=portal;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=micportal;Password=150302;language=us_english"/>

    <add name="NfceConnPortalExterno"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
             connectionString="Data Source=10.10.0.1,8081;Initial Catalog=portal;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=micportal;Password=\\-W?98xpT;language=us_english"/>


    <!-- this one will be modified in runtime. -->
    <add
      name="NfceContext"
      connectionString="data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=Blogging;Connection Timeout=320;Persist Security Info=True;integrated security=True;language=us_english;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    

  </connectionStrings>
```

In my DbContext i have this:

```
public NfceContext() : base("name=NfceContext")
{

}
```

Im trying an approach of changing this connectionString in a class, using **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile**. If i check running on debug mode, the connectionStrings on the app.vshost.exe.config is changed, but the app.config not(I guess that the app.config should be modified).

When i try to do for an example: context.MyEntity.ToList(), it´s gives me an error like this"you don´t have permission to create table..." and if i check the connection string at this time, it´s the old one(before i modify).

The code bellow can show what i said:

Method to overwrite the connection string in the app.config:

```
private void ModifyNfceContext(string dataSource, string portal, string senha)
{    
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

    XmlNodeList lista = xml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(String.Format("connectionStrings/add [@name='{0}']", "NfceContext")); 
    XmlNode node = lista[0];

    string connectionString = node.Attributes["connectionString"].Value;
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder connStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
    connStringBuilder.InitialCatalog = portal;
    connStringBuilder.DataSource = dataSource;
    connStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    connStringBuilder.UserID = "mic" + portal;
    connStringBuilder.Password = senha;

    node.Attributes["connectionString"].Value = connStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
    xml.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);    
}
```

The controller´s contructor:

```
public NfceController()
        {
            if (this.context == null)
            {
                ModifyNfceContext(this.dataSource, this.portal, this.senha);
                //At this moment, the connectionString should be modified.
                this.context = new NfceContext();       
            }   

            this.repositoryNfce = new RepositoryNfce(context);
        }
```

So, what am i doing wrong? Do i need to change the app.config instead of vhost.config?

Comment: a) does your user-account have the privileges to change a config file? (In \Program Files\...)

Comment: b) changing an active config with XmlDoc is asking for trouble...

Comment: a): yes, he has.
b): i wonder about changing in memory and not physical, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your NfceContext is not static object, you can create another constructor what will take a connection string name as the parametr, something like this:

```
public class NfceContext : DbContext{
   public NfceContext (string appConfigConStrName) : base (appConfigConStrName) { }
}
```

Otherwise, if your context is static object, what is bad practice as I think, you can write public method what will create new instance of DbContext inside your NfceContext:

```
public class NfceContext : DbContext{
  static NfceContext context;

  public static NfceContext() {
     context = new NfceContext();
  }

  public void ChangeDB(string appConfigConStr) {
      context = new NfceContext(appConfigConStr);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @ArhiChief,  i have alread tryed this approach, passing a new connectionString that a have built manually, but in the Repository for an example, when i try to do something like context.Entity.ToList(), i get an error(have no permission to create database), but i dont want to create the database, just query this.

Comment: Probably, if you use Code First, your domain model and model of your databases aren't match and your error also rise than database in connection string really doesn't exists. Did you try to doing something like this: 'var db = new NfceContext(conStr1); \* some actions *\ db = new NfceContext(conStr2);'? Also, be sure that your DbContext domain model is same for all databases you use.

Comment: You are right, i was missing some properties in my domain model. The models aren´t matching.
I will modify and give you an answer

Comment: That´s it! I disregarded the approach of changing the connection string in the app.config and passed the connectionstring in the constructor.
Also, checked for the domain model and the database model match.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it's to late, but I want to make some additions about model matching. If you use Code First with enabled migrations make sure what you add migrations to all databases you want to use. You need to do that, because EF model creation process reads data from dbo.__MigrationHistory table of attached DB and compare it with last migration. EF use this to make sure yourself that model of DB and it's own domain models are same.  But there is some "wall hack" what can turn off this step: you need to exclude Migrations folder from your project and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had written [this article](http://www.programmersranch.com/2013/11/c-ef-setting-connection-strings-at.html) on setting connection strings at runtime for database first. Check it out; it might be useful even in your case.

In short, you can create a partial class to get access to a DbContext constructor overload that takes a connection string as a parameter (example from my article):

```
public partial class peopleEntities : DbContext
{
    public peopleEntities(String connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {

    }
}
```

And then you can use EntityConnectionStringBuilder to build and pass the connection string (example also from my article):

```
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder csb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            csb.Metadata = "res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl";
            csb.Provider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0";
            csb.ProviderConnectionString = "data source=people.sdf";
            String entityConnStr = csb.ToString();
```

Comment: Just-a-links isn't a good answer here. Either make a summary or post this as a comment.

Comment: The article is a bit long to post the entire thing, don't you think? Even a summary would miss the point.

Comment: @gigi, i have used the approach for not changing the app.config manually and just passing the new connectionString in the constructor.